# Copy table from one server to another in python(Sybase temporary table)

Tags: python, sybase

```
import sybpydb
import pandas

bConn = sybpydb.connect(user='user', password='password', servername='DEV03')
DbCur = bConn.cursor()

DbCur.execute("select Top 1 *  Into #TmpTbl from ConnectionInfo")
bConn.commit()

df = pandas.read_sql("Select * From #TmpTbl", this.bConn)
print(df)

bConn1 = sybpydb.connect(user='user', password='password', servername='QCP01')
DbCur1 = bConn.cursor()
```

I want to copy #TmpTbl to QCP01 server(Using bConn1) . Is there any way to bring TmpTbl data to QCP01?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Other than the obvious "read from bConn, write to bConn1", you may want to see what it takes to utilize the Sybase bulkcopy libraries (makes for faster reads/writes), and possibly mix in some python pipes (eg, [How do pipes in Python work](https://www.quora.com/How-do-pipes-in-Python-work))

Comment: @markp-Can you please explain little bit more? or if you provide me any example that will work. Thanks.